# Python decimal.InvalidOperation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

i'm always getting this error when running something like this:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec =30

b=("2/3")

Decimal(b)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    Decimal(b)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

Also, why do i get this result from the console?

```
>>> Decimal(2/3)
Decimal('0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Decimal`'s initializer can't accept strings with a slash in them. Informally, the string has to look like a single number. [This table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?#decimal.Decimal) shows the proper format for string arguments. If you want to calculate 2/3, do

```
>>> Decimal(2)/Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.6666666666666666666666666667')
```

`Decimal(2/3)` gives `Decimal('0.66666666666666662965923251249478198587894439697265625')` because 2/3 evaluates to a floating point number, and floats have inherently limited precision. That's the closest the computer can get to representing `2/3` using a float.

Comment: Also true for the other arithmetic symbols!

Comment: Or use `fractions.Fraction(2, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem like this

```
from decimal import *

b = (Decimal(2) / Decimal(3)).quantize(Decimal(1)/(10**Decimal(30)))

Decimal(b)
```

quantize allows you to get the necessary accuracy